# Unable to Compress MP3 with Flac

Tags: audio, flac

I am trying to use FLAC to compress an mp3 file like below:

```bsh
flac -8 1-5f15c799beb953837480f0e29d872eb9.mp3
```

However, I keep getting the error
`ERROR: input file 1-5f15c799beb953837480f0e29d872eb9.mp3 has an ID3v2 tag`.

I have read through numerous stack exchange answers such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39185/command-line-tool-to-remove-selected-tags-from-mp3-files#39194), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26911/erase-and-rewrite-mp3-id3-tags), or
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193065/how-to-remove-id3-audio-tag-image-or-metadata-from-mp3-with-ffmpeg).

One of the answers suggested using ffmpeg but I received an error regarding something with tags. I then tried using eyeD3 but when I installed it with pip3 install, I wasn't able to run the binary file.

The most promising approach was using ip3v2. I did `sudo apt-get install ip3v2` and then ran `id3v2 -s 1-5f15c799beb953837480f0e29d872eb9.mp3` which gave the ouptut

```
Stripping id3 tag in "1-5f15c799beb953837480f0e29d872eb9.mp3"...id3v1 stripped.
```

When I tried running the flac command again, it failed again saying that ID3v2 tags were still present. Does anyone have any ideas on where I can strip these ID3v2 tags?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I literally figured out the issue after posting this. I was doing id3v2 -s which strips ID3v1 tags. Use id3v2 -d to remove ID3v2 tags.

```
id3v2 -d 1-5f15c799beb953837480f0e29d872eb9.mp3
```